# Can't Get the Syntax to Work for this XML Soap Request - 400 Error

Tags: reactjs, xml, api, soap, syntax

Working with a SOAP API in React JS and all is fine except for this one function keeps returning a 400 error.

Using Axios to make the POST request with the following syntax.

The goal is to obtain a specific client ID and be able to edit specified fields.

```
let getExtraInfo = `<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateClientAdditionalFields xmlns="http://www.ozsoft.com.au/VETtrak/api/complete">
      <token>${token}</token>
      <clientCode>09224</clientCode>
      <additionalFieldData>
        <AdditionalData>
          <Gender>M</Gender>
        </AdditionalData>
      </additionalFieldData>
    </UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`
```

Here is a link to the API

https://sthservices.ozsoft.com.au/SIU_API/VT_API.asmx?op=UpdateClientAdditionalFields

I have tried every combination to get the request to work correctly but I believe the issue may be to incorrect syntax on the API end.

For reference here is my API call using Axios.

```
async function GetTimetableData(xmlsChosen){
     const response = await axios.post('https://thingproxy.freeboard.io/fetch/https://sthservices.ozsoft.com.au/SIU_API/VT_API.asmx?wsdl',
      xmlsChosen,
      { 
          headers:{ 
                    'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
      }).then(res=>{
        var jsonObj = parse(res.data);
       // setCourseChosen(jsonObj.["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"].GetOccurrenceExtendedDetailsResponse.GetOccurrenceExtendedDetailsResult.OccuExtended);     
          console.log(jsonObj);
      }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);
      }).finally(() => {
        
      });  
  }
```

Would anyone be able to provide some insight as to how to do this request using React JS. I have asked the devs directly but their responses are in PHP and doesn't help with this specific issue.

The list of additional fields can also be found here.

https://customer.vettrak.com.au/hc/en-us/articles/360002285835

I can provide more information if needed.

**UPDATE**

I have added the headers and checked that the token is correct - I also don't have issues making other requests with the token with other functions.

I have tried the syntax below.

```
`<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:com="http://www.ozsoft.com.au/VETtrak/api/complete">
<soap:Body>
  <com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
     <com:token>676767676</com:token>
     <com:clientCode>09224</com:clientCode>
     <com:additionalFieldData>"<com:AdditionalData><com:Gender>M></com:Gender></com:AdditionalData>"</com:additionalFieldData>
  </com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`
```

```
`<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:com="http://www.ozsoft.com.au/VETtrak/api/complete">
<soap:Body>
  <com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
     <com:token>${token}</com:token>
     <com:clientCode>09224</com:clientCode>
     <com:additionalFieldData><AdditionalData><Gender>M><Gender><AdditionalData></com:additionalFieldData>
  </com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`
```

If I do the following request

```
`<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:com="http://www.ozsoft.com.au/VETtrak/api/complete">
<soap:Body>
  <com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
     <com:token>${token}</com:token>
     <com:clientCode>09224</com:clientCode>
     <com:additionalFieldData><com:AdditionalData>string</com:AdditionalData></com:additionalFieldData>
  </com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`
```

I get a "A problem occurred when parsing the additional data XML: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." Error. I know the token and client code are fine as when I don't include them I get an Authentication Error / Client doesn't exist response.

Then when I do:

```
`<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:com="http://www.ozsoft.com.au/VETtrak/api/complete">
<soap:Body>
  <com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
     <com:token>${token}</com:token>
     <com:clientCode>09224</com:clientCode>
     <com:additionalFieldData><com:AdditionalData><gender>M</gender><com:/AdditionalData></com:additionalFieldData>
  </com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`
```

I get the usual 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the `UpdateClientAdditionalFields` inside the WSDL, it seems one of your parameters is wrong. The top element is defined as:

```
  <s:element name="UpdateClientAdditionalFields">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="token" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="clientCode" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="additionalFieldData" type="s:string"/>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
```

`additionalFieldData` is a string, but you are sending an XML in your message:

```
  <additionalFieldData>
    <AdditionalData>
      <Gender>M</Gender>
    </AdditionalData>
  </additionalFieldData>
```

Try with a string or without this field just to see if it works (since it is optional `minOccurs="0"`).

Also, your token may be wrong:

```
<token>${token}</token>
```

Is this a variable that you need to replace before the call?

Add also a HTTP header named [SOAPAction](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528) like this:

```
SOAPAction: "http://www.ozsoft.com.au/VETtrak/api/complete/UpdateClientAdditionalFields"
```

Try again with these changes and see if it works.

**EDIT** based on comments:

Are you sending proper values for the `token`, `clientCode`, and `additionalFieldData` elements? I mean actual, usable values, all of type string, not placeholders like `${token}` or XML elements instead of string values?

Your SOAP request should look like this (don't forget to add the `SOAPAction` HTTP header):

```
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:com="http://www.ozsoft.com.au/VETtrak/api/complete">
   <soap:Body>
      <com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
         <com:token>proper value here</com:token>
         <com:clientCode>proper value here</com:clientCode>
         <com:additionalFieldData>proper value here</com:additionalFieldData>
      </com:UpdateClientAdditionalFields>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for getting back to me. I have tried everything you said and still can't get it to work. When I don't include the fields it gives me a response saying "Unable to apply additional data: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s"

Comment: Hi! Thanks for getting back to me. 

Which parameter is wrong? It all looks correct to me.

I have tried everything you said and still can't get it to work. When I don't include the fields it gives me a response saying "Unable to apply additional data: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s"

Also the token variable is just being passed in from when the user is authenticated. If the token is wrong it just returns a unauthorized response to the request. So no issue with the token.

Comment: @simlimsd4: see update on my answer. Too long to post as a comment.

Comment: thanks for the reply - but still no luck. I know the token works because I make other requests with it. Even when I manually input the token I get a 400 error regardless if the token is correct or not which makes me think its still an error with my syntax. I have tried everything suggested. I have updated my question to reflect what else I have done.

Comment: You didn't try everything suggested. You are still sending XML markup for the `additionalFieldData` field when the WSDL says clearly that it is a `string`, not an XML element. What is the documentation for the `additionalFieldData` saying. What do you need to send there and in what format?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Here is the documentation http://support.vettrak.com.au/api/VETtrakAPI444/VT_API_UpdateClientAdditionalFields@string@string@string.html AND here is the documentation for additional fields available.https://customer.vettrak.com.au/hc/en-us/articles/115009529007-VETtrak-API-Additional-data-documentation-17-2-x-

I received a response back from the api devs as well and they had a variable called data which was a string that had the same formatting as XML.